# Scrambled characters when output PDF with FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have something strange that's happening with an application of mine. When using FPDF to output a pdf to the screen it spits out a load of random characters.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

[image]

Comment: Do you send the `Content-Type: application/pdf` header?

Comment: @Maerlyn FPDF does this automatically.

Comment: Are you using images in your .pdf? I've encountered this when the images are not the type you specify (.png vs. .jpg)

Comment: It was working perfectly until I ran composer update on my application. weirdly though it works fine locally, it's just on the production server

Comment: If you use the Chrome inspector (or Firebug) can you show what the content header is set to? Maybe something in your server config is rewriting the app/pdf header? You might also try replacing the fpdf lib on your prod server with a fresh copy from the web (maybe something got corrupted?)